# ¿Cómo crear botones con sus respectivos valores en php?

Tags: php, html

Intentando crear una calculadora más completa con botónes y todo, me topé con un problema: Los números que tienen mis botones, no aparecen representados donde deberían. En el input llamado "Pantalla" debería estar representado un echo de los números que el usuario aprete con los botones, pero me aparece por GET que los números si aparecen bien, pero no se representan en la variable $pantalla.

Código php y html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Calculadora</title>
    <center><h1>Calculadora</h1></center>
    <center><p>Escribir el primer numero en la primera casilla, luego elegir qué calculo básico a utilizar. Al final colocar el último numero para realizar así el calculo.</p></center>
</head>
<body>


<?php

if (isset($r)) {
    $n1=$screen;
    $op="-";
    $screen=0;
}

if (isset($s)) {
    $n1=$screen;
    $op="+";
    $screen=0;
}

if (isset($m)) {
    $n1=$screen;
    $op="*";
    $screen=0;
}

if (isset($d)) {
    $n1=$screen;
    $op="/";
    $screen=0;
}

if (isset($i)) {

    unset($newop);
    switch ($op) {
        case '+':
            echo $screen=$screen+$n1;
            break;

            case "-":
            echo $screen=$screen-$n1;
            break;

            case "*":
            echo $screen=$screen*$n1;
            break;

            case "/":
            echo $screen=$screen/$n1;
            break;
    }
    unset($op);
    }
    if (!isset($num)) {
        $num= 0;
    }
    if (!isset($screen)) {
        $screen=0;
    }

?>
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="GET">

<?php
if(isset($newop))
{
?>
<input type="hidden" name="newop" value="Estamos en una nueva operacion" >
<?php
}
?>

<?php
if(isset($op))
{
?>
<input type="hidden" name="op" value="<?php echo $op; ?>" >
<?php
}
?>


<?php
if(isset($n1))
{
?>
<input type="hidden" name="n1" value="<?php echo $n1; ?>" >
<?php
}
?>

<br>
<br>
<input type="Text" name="screen" value="<?php echo $screen; ?>" size="20">
<br>
<input type="submit" name="num" value="1">
<input type="submit" name="num" value="2">
<input type="submit" name="num" value="3">

<br>
<input type="submit" name="num" value="4">
<input type="submit" name="num" value="5">
<input type="submit" name="num" value="6">

<br>
<input type="submit" name="num" value="7">
<input type="submit" name="num" value="8">
<input type="submit" name="num" value="9">
<br>
<div>
<input type="submit" name="s" value="+">
<br>
<input type="submit" name="r" value="-">
<input type="submit" name="m" value="*">
<br>
<input type="submit" name="d" value="/">
<input type="submit" name="i" value="=">
<br>
</div>
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Te doy la bienvenida a SO. No hay ninguna variable llamada `$pantalla` en tu extenso código. Además, debes explicarnos la lógica, porque no es evidente tener que meterse en la mente de otro para adivinar la lógica que está usando  y luego encontrar el error. ¿Cuál es la lógica y cuál es el error (señala en qué línea o parte del código se encuentra)?

Comment: Gracias por contestar! Me equivoque, quise decir $screen. La lógica que planteo es que cuando el usuario aprete algún botón, el número de este se vea representado en la variable $screen que es el único input de texto. Además, una vez que escribió el primer valor y apretó algún calculo, ya sea suma, resta etc, se borre el primer valor y pueda insertar el siguiente para así apretar enter y dar el resultado en la misma variable. El error es que al apretar los botones, no aparece en el input el número correspondiente, no aparece absolutamente nada.

Comment: Intente utilizar return donde ahora estan los echo en el switch, así los valores de $screen se guardaban y podía llamarlos con el echo que esta en el input del código html, pero se ve que aún no entiendo muy bien cómo utilizar el return

Comment: `return` se usa en funciones, dentro de un `switch` no tiene sentido. A lo sumo lo puedes guardar en una variable o algo así si lo necesitas en otra parte. De todos modos si no explicas el código es difícil ayudarte. Es un programa que nadie conoce y una lógica que nadie entiende, solamente tú. Tampoco queda claro cuál es el problema en sí, qué resultado obtienes o qué error y que es lo que esperas obtener.

Comment: Intentare ser lo más claro:
las variables llamadas "S, R, M, D, I" son las variables son las variables representadas para la suma, resta, mult, division y la $i es el resultado total.

coloqué un if para saber que si la $i fue apretada, que borre con un UNSET la variable $op que contenía el primer número a calcular. Una vez borrada la variable, colocar un switch para saber qué funcion de las 4 el usuario eligió y así borrar el otro número y ser reemplazado por el resultado.

el problema es que no me aparecen los números de $screen en el input text por lo que no puedo hacer nada